# Hide/Show elements from a ChildViewController in my main view

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have a main view with a custom tap bar menu, a content view and a top bar.

In my content view, I `addChildViewController` and `removeFromParentViewController` child depending on which sender in my tap bar menu has been selected.

In some `childview` added with `addSubview` method in my content view, I have some `UIscrollView`.

In my `childview`, with `UIscrollViewDelegate`, I use an if-else condition to know where is my `scrollcontent` (`contentOffset >=50` etc...).

Depending the answer, I need to hide/show some elements in my main view (`mainview` > `topbar` > `elements` that are in a different `UIViewController`)  , unfortunately I'm unable to target them. **Is there a way to target those elements ?**

**Please consider the following sketch** (of the previously detailed info):

[image]

Comment: you can implement Notification Pattern for the same. Fire notification in your mainView. Make your second ViewController as listener of the notification and do changes i.e. hide/show elements when required.

Comment: thanks @luckyShubhra : your answer put me on the right way.
As you could imagine, I'm a newbie in Swift, expect playing with `prepareForSegue`, I'm not used to implement `notification` and `observer`.

Comment: M glad u could resolve your issue. I didn't knew u were newbie else I would helped you in implementation. Do let me know if you have any issues again. Thanks!!